# PyDroid interpreter "64-bit instead of 32-bit"

Tags: python, pydroid

AT Hello ran into trouble that my interpreter PyDroid decided to throw an error

```
error: "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/ aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3.9" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
```

Happened after changing device, previously used Redmi, moved to a better device Samsung a22 and yet to support some things I use mobile and after installing the application, I was able to download the libraries and updated the application, after that, any actions to install the library or run any code give this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In general, "[executable] is 64-bit instead of 32-bit" means exactly what it says. You need to install a 32-bit interpreter if you're targeting 32-bit hardware (or 64-bit hardware running a 32-bit kernel).